# More Idiomatic Way to Describe This Relationship in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a relationship between two models using a pivot table. Here's the basic structure.

```
Users
  id
  name

Links
  link_id
  user_id_from
  user_id_to

Checkout
  id
  user_id
  text
```

The idea is that `User`s have `Checkouts` assigned to them. They can also `Link` to other `User`s. This will allow that `User` to access any `Checkout`s that are assigned to other `User`s. For example, if the record (3, 5) exists in `Links`, then User 5 will be able to see all of User 3's `Checkout`s.

Using `hasManyThrough` or `belongsToMany` isn't an option. This is because Eloquent only links by the primary key (`id` in this case) when using those relationship helpers. It won't allow the `Checkout` model to be selected via `user_id` instead.

I could use `load` hypothetically and just call `usersLinkedToMe` (see below), then `load` 'checkouts'. But I really want only a collection of the checkouts themselves in one call, not having to worry about pulling the checkouts nested in the `User` objects.

Therefore, right now, this is how I have the relationship working:

```
// The users (my) own checkouts
public function checkouts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Checkout::class, 'user_id');
}

// The users who are linked to me, sharing their checkouts with me
public function usersLinkedToMe() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'links', 'user_id_to', 'user_id_from')
}

// The checkouts of the users who are linked to me (sharing with me)
public function linkedCheckouts()
{
    return Checkout::whereIn('user_id', $this->usersLinkedToMe()->pluck('user_id_from')->toArray())->get();
}
```

The focus of course is on `linkedCheckouts`. This works how I want. But since I'm new to Eloquent, I feel like I'm just hacking around the problem. It seems like there should be a more idiomatic (natural) way to be able to call this relationship using Eloquent.

What is a more proper way of declaring the "relationship" in `linkedCheckouts`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Query Scopes' for this situation. I would use 'Local scope' for this. Read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes